# Magento Auto Add Items Based on Quantity

Tags: magento

I'm designing a custom product page with a button that when clicked I need to have an alert come up with a "Yes" or "No" option.

If "Yes" is selected I then need the following to happen.

Add another product into the cart based on the products quantity i.e. between 1 & 2 items add product A between 3 & 4 Items product B, between 5 & 12 product C and so on.

Any idea of the best way to accomplish this?

It has to be a alert style popup (ajax popup preferred) cannot be a checkbox on the product page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've come across a solution to my problem...  I'm using a Simple Modal (That TheBlackBenzKid hinted me to) that I'm either going to call from a custom button or with the add to cart button.  This in turn will redirect to a php page that will redirect to the cart.  For the php page I'll just include the code to put a item into the cart from there anyone could figure out how to customize it to there own needs.

```
<?php
// Include Magento application (URL to Mage.php)
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );
umask(0);

//specified quantity my own variable I'm using for quantities
$spqty = 9;

// Initialize Magento
Mage::app("default");

// You have two options here,
// "frontend" for frontend session or "adminhtml" for admin session
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));


$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

// get the current Magento cart
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');


if ($spqty <= 2) {

// insert item to cart where "98" is the product ID (NOT SKU!) Where "2" is the quantity
$cart->addProduct(98, array('qty' => 2));


} elseif ($spqty >= 4 ){

// you can add multiple products at the same time by adding this line multiple times
$cart->addProduct(96, array('qty' => 3));

}

// save the cart
$cart->save();

// very straightforward, set the cart as updated
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);


// redirect to index.php
header("Location: index.php/checkout/cart");
```

I also found some of this information from this guys blog I'll link to the article

[How to add a product from an external site into Magento](http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2009/04/27/how-to-add-a-product-into-magento-from-an-external-site/)

I'm happy to answer any questions on this...

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best answer, but code to get you started:
You could make the cart function use:

```
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:nValidateForm();"/>
```

And your form code:

```
<form name="m2mform" id="m2mform" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:nValidateForm();">
```

And then just call an external JavaScript in your page XML headers and add it to cart so that JS file will always be checked and validate the popup.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply that Simple Modal Confirm Override looks like it will do the trick perfectly for the popup!  However, I really need help with the syntax for auto adding items to the cart if they select yes and how to conditionally do it based on quantity of the previous item added to cart.

Comment: Sorry, this is one of the reasons that Magento bugs me. Its far to complex to do simple quick hacks. You could look at OpenCart an MVC PHP based cart, much faster and more robust including configuration and modifying of code. I am sorry but I can be no further help.

Comment: Yeah tell me about it...  This is what the client wants though and they're not willing to waiver on platform, design, or operation.  Thank you again for the help with the modal confirm.  Exactly what I needed for that.

Comment: There are some better ones like http://defunkt.io/facebox/ and check out google keywords: jquery modal boxes, jquery window boxes. Shame on that really. I am in the same boat, Magento is like very locked down and there is no real edits - much is XML template driver, then phtml template driven.. and not all things are editable. My links menu for example is impossible to edit - I did a search in the entire magento code for all the combos of my account and my links menu and it does not exist!